# Growth on raspberry cane: What is it?

Tags: botany, pathology, fruit

I have raspberries growing in my garden.

One of the raspberry canes has some sort of **growth** on it.

- Size: Approximately 2 inches long
- Location: Zone 5; east of Toronto, Ontario, Canada
- Date: April 4, 2019.

**What is the growth?** Is it insects, fungus, bacteria, a defect, or something else?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but possibly the [raspberry cane midge, Resselialla theobaldi](https://books.google.nl/books?id=wox5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=Cecidomyiidae+raspberry&source=bl&ots=uYo-1r8OYZ&sig=ACfU3U3X6sepFqNkvbCZ9cTv4pt3wvHgtQ&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjt04STufPhAhXNbVAKHY0wAWwQ6AEwCnoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=Cecidomyiidae%20raspberry&f=false)? Or some other cane midge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A botanist at a local university says it is most definitely **Crown Gall**.

---

He didn't provide any other information than that, so all I can do is quote Wikipedia:

> ***Agrobacterium tumefaciens*** (updated scientific name ***Rhizobium radiobacter***, synonym ***Agrobacterium radiobacter***) is the causal
>   agent of crown gall disease (the formation of tumours) in over 140
>   species of eudicots.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrobacterium_tumefaciens